# Nodejs WriteStream "finish" event is firing early

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream

I'm trying to remove the first few bytes of a large file in node js and write the resulting contents to a new file.

I do so by creating a readstream with the existing file and setting an offset, then piping that into a writestream for an output file.

```
const inputStream = createReadStream(inputPath, {
    start: NUM_BYTES_OFFSET,
  });

const outputStream = createWriteStream(outputPath);

inputStream.pipe(outputStream);

await new Promise((resolve) => outputStream.on("finish", resolve));

return;
```

When logging the on 'data' event from the inputStream, I see that either 0 or 1 chunk is written to the output file before the 'finish' event fires, the promise resolves, and the function returns. I'm left with a tiny output file.

How do I ensure that the entire file is written to the output destination before the function returns?